# Checkbox "to accept the license agreement" on Yii and processing steps

Tags: php, yii

I made a registration form on the site, using the model User (table tbl_user). And the required fields through the rules.

But, how do I handle the value of the field that is not on the table? Namely checkbox: "to accept the license agreement. And throw an error if the option is not selected?

What should be added to the User model and how to handle the error in the controller?

P.S. Sorry if the question is very stupid. But I am new to Yii, so a little confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U can do it as shown

Your View File

```
<div class="row rememberMe" id="CHECKBOX">
        <?php echo $form->checkBox($regForm,'agree'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->label($regForm,'agree'); ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::link("terms and Conditions",array('message/goodbye'));?>
        <?php echo $form->error($regForm,'agree'); ?>
    </div>
```

create a form extending cform model as shown below

Pass in view ur RegisterationForm model

```
$regForm =new RegistrationForm
```

And in ur Registeration Form do like as shown

```
class RegistrationForm extends CFormModel
{
public $agree;

public function rules()
    {
       return array(
     array('agree', 'required', 'requiredValue' => 1, 'message' => 'You should accept term to use our service'),
);
}
public function attributeLabels(){
        'agree' => 'I agree the',
}
```

Comment: Added another answer to this comment

Comment: Should I place all elements on this form or just checkbox "accept terms"?

Comment: Sorry dude i have to leave now try reading the documentation if u did not get i ll help u out tomorrow. Ill post my registration code tomor

Answer (score 1):

As you wish if u dont not want to bind attributes to database you can use CFORM MODEL or you can use Cactive Record .Its Better to use CFORM Model where there is no database interactions you can check yiis default contact tab they have used CFORM MODEL . When u want to collect just data no databse interactions u can use CFORM MODEL

Where do u want to save data in database then u should copy to database model and save it this is only to collect the attributes values for example consider this as your cactive model

```
$model=new User() //this extends Cactive record
$regForm=new Registerationform () // this extends CForm Model
```

Now If u want to save to model do like this

```
$model->attribute=$regForm->AttributeValue
$model->save();
```

The Use of this method is only that there is no need to change the whole model which is extended by CACTIVERECORD when u need to change or add some extra  field in your database table u can just add attribute to your CFORMMODEL model and do as above

Comment: Ok. But i could not save data from this form. RegistrationForm extends CFormModel has not method save().

Comment: U can also add agree attribute in your User model and add the code as showed in my previous post to rules method of user

Comment: How validate form and save result? $regForm->validate() and $model->save()? Can i get attributes this way: $model->attributes=$regFordm->attributes?

Comment: Check the code for Contact tab that is provided when you create a new yii application you will get it. And you cannot get $model->attributes=$regFordm->attribute this way u have to get the $regFordm->attribute first create the instance of user attach to it and save in database

Comment: Contact not saved info in DB ((

Comment: I have problems: i cannot validate RegisterForm. $model = new RegisterForm(); => $model->attributes=$_POST['RegisterForm']; => $model->validate() throw exception ((

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32017/discussion-between-ninad-and-frops)

Comment: The error is that either your database table name is not correct for what you are validating or you are calling some invalid method with this model.Post your controller and model code

Comment: CFormModel need int specify tableName? Why? In LoginForm (example in yii) not specified tableName.

Comment: I have explained you that in my answer

Comment: How to tie CFormModel (RegisterForm) and CActiveRecord (User)?

Comment: U tell me what is your functionality and what you want to achieve in new question you will get the answer